# What is LocalBroadcastManager in Android

Tags: android

I  don't have an idea about LocalBroadcastManager in the android. 
Links and blogs are highly appreciable.

Comment: local means not remote, remote in this case means cross process (so it would be work only in the same application instance)

Comment: @Selvin what is differnce between  LocalBroadcastManager and Broadcast Manager

Comment: You will find the best answer inside the api. LocalebroadcastManager: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html  and BoradcastReceiver http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

Comment: they have only common interface, LocalBroadcastManager is a simple publish–subscribe pattern implementation which doesn't involve OS ... the "normal" if for rpc (that's why "normal" is "more expensive")

Answer (score 4):

**LocalBroadcastManager :-**

LocalBroadcast receiver used for inter-process communication which provides application security has it doesn’t allow other process to communicate.
Also these broadcast not accessible outside the application so it also provide system security.

You don’t need to register in menifest has it is in local in app it is efficient.

Application gets crash if you are passing intent filter null
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).register(broadcast,null);

**Register broadcast :-**
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).register(broadcast, new intent filter);

**UnRegister broadcast :-** 
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).unregister(broadcast);

**Send Broadcast :-**
LocalBrodcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(new  Intent())

you can refer below given link

[how to use LocalBroadcastManager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802157/how-to-use-localbroadcastmanager)

so many people doesn't know about How to measure whether broadcast is send successfully or not.

**sendBroadcast(receiver) :-** which returns true or false.
true - broadcast send successfully to register receiver.
false - broadcast not register.

Answer (score 2):

[Local broadcast manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) is a events consumer/raiser system that lives only into the app that raise event. You can subscribe with:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);
```

and can raise event:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(MainActivity.this).sendBroadcast(new Intent("intent action")
```